# re.findall() with everything except certain text

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, findall

I'm trying to program a vocabulary game.

I am using a regular expression to hide my word, which I have to guess. I'm not comfortable with the syntax used with regular expressions - outwith the simple examples, I get very confused.

Take for example the *chosen_word*

```
'TO CRANK (STH) UP'
```

With RegExs I manage to hide the keywords and I have *hidden_word* as follows:

```
TO _ _ _ _ _   (STH)  _ _
```

Now, I'm firstly trying to create a list of all hidden letters, so I can reveal one at a time at the user's request. In this specific example, I want the list to contain every hidden letter in the string, that is, every alphabetic letter except the initial 'TO' and the STH in brackets. In essence, I want to get:

```
C, R, A, N, K, U, P
```

I've been trying with this RegEx:

```
chosen_word = "TO CRANK (STH) UP"
hidden_letters = re.findall(r"(?!TO|STH)[A-Z]", chosen_word)
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
O, C, R, A, N, K, T, H, U, P
```

That is, it's only excluding the first letter of the specified words (T for 'TO', and S for 'STH). But if add parenthesis to capture them together:

```
hidden_letters = re.findall(r"(?!(TO)|(STH))[A-Z]", chosen_word)
```

What I get a weird result: a list of commas, when there are no commas in the original string.

```
(",", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",")
```

What's happening? How do I get the method to capture what I want?

Also, once I get that sorted, the idea is to then choose one of those letters randomly, for which I use the random library and I choose one letter at random, removing it from the list to avoid repetition through different rounds:

```
if first_reveal == True:
    hidden_letters = re.findall(r"(?!TO|STH)[A-Z]", chosen_word)
    first_reveal = False
                  
letter = random.choice(hidden_letters)
                    
hidden_letters.remove(letter)
```

If I get the RegEx right, underscores and letters will map each other exactly. That is, say my code randomly chooses letter 'K', that is the 5th letter of the list, I want it to replace the 5th underscore in my hidden word. But I don't know how to get that started! Any hints?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
import re
chosen_word = "TO CRANK (STH) UP"
hidden_letters = re.findall(r"(?:\bTO\b|\(STH\))|([A-Z])", chosen_word)
print(list(filter(None,hidden_letters)))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##VcyxCsIwEIDhvU9xZLqD6uImiBQXQWhF46IRsSalgZiEa0CEvnusm@7//8V36oNf5GyfMXACNsWjD4Pxt1dgDSsQsoHNoap3gEe5JTjtRdFbrafCmZQMD1PEZt5Zr@/OIQtcL1UrG9WO6rsoohEv1ex8JVHCD05FZOsTOjsk7KybLKyDN@U/T0Q5fwA).

**Results**: `['C', 'R', 'A', 'N', 'K', 'U', 'P']`.

**Regex**:

```py
(?:\bTO\b|\(STH\))|([A-Z])
```

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TO                       'TO'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    STH                      'STH'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

**Note**: [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns captured texts if the regex pattern contains capturing groups in it.